# PDF Encrypted Strings within Content Streams

Tags: pdf

I am trying to decrypt a PDF file by following Section 7.6 Encryption of the PDF 320000-1:2008 specification, rather than using a third-party library. Given the correct password, I can successfully decrypt the COS strings (such as those found in the indirect object referenced by the trailer's /Info key) and also the content streams; both return readable text. However, I now see that the strings *within* the content streams are also encrypted.

```
BT
/F1 9 Tf
1 0 0 1 72 72 Tm
(òø@Ä) Tj
ET
```

I've unsuccessfully tried to decrypt these strings using the same RC4 decryption key that I used for the stream that contained them (which depends on the object number and generation.)

Am I supposed to derive a different key to decrypt these inner strings?

Comment: *"the strings within the content streams are also encrypted"* - they are **not encrypted**, their **encoding** merely is different from your expectation.  As you mention ISO 32000-1, you can easily find information on font encoding therein.  In your pdf simply look up the **F1** font resource and look for a **ToUnicode** or **Encoding** entry in it.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I can see there is an Encoding entry that eventually points to a dictionary with 256 Differences entries. Further down the rabbit hole I go...